# How do I filter tags down to specific categories?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have this working query here that will retrieve tags used in the last 60 days.

```
$term_ids = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT DISTINCT wp_term_taxonomy.term_id, wp_terms.name
FROM wp_term_taxonomy
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
INNER JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), $show_tags_in_days) <= $wpdb->posts.post_date", ARRAY_A);
```

What I need to modify this to is tags used in the last 60 days AND in a specific Wordpress category. This will be used on a category page of Wordpress. I've been fiddling with this for awhile and I think I've just got myself all confused. Is there a way to do this with another join or should I run two separate queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. Here is the query I came up with.

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_term_taxonomy.term_id, wp_terms.name FROM wp_terms
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON   wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id=wp_terms.term_ID
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID=wp_term_relationships.object_id
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND wp_posts.ID IN (
SELECT wp_posts.ID FROM wp_terms
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id=wp_terms.term_ID
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID=wp_term_relationships.object_id
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' AND wp_terms.term_id=$cur_cat_id) LIMIT 10
```

Here is a more in-depth explanation: http://www.ohthecode.com/wordpress/most-used-tags-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

This query retrieves *only* taxonomy IDs.  It is likely that you are using the $term_ids variable in another query to retrieve the posts that have both a tag from the list in the $term_ids variable *and* are in the category.  In other words, find the place where you are actually retrieving posts and pass in both the $term_ids and the category id you are interested in.

However, since you say that you are doing this on a category template page (say category-mycategory.php), you may not need to do anything additional at all since the category should be passed in automatically.

Comment: I was using the query to show "Trending tags". It had nothing to do with posts. It was a sidebar widget that was suppose to show the top 10 tags used in that category. However, I did figure it out. I'm going to update my question with the answer. :)